# Rectangle Tool pitched 15 degrees in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools

Whenever I click on the "Rectangle Tool" the resulting rectangle is always pitched 15 degrees up, on the right hand side. The solution I am sure is simple and probably too simple for this forum, but how do I change this back to the normal setting?

Comment: What is you Illustrator version ? Please check by click Help-->About Illustrator.
i have AI CC 2015 and dont have problem like you.

Answer (score 2):

Go to :

```
Edit>Preferences>General>Constrain Angle
```

The angle there should be 0.
[image]

Wish helps,

Answer (score 0):

Your 3D pespective grid might be on - try SHFT+CTRL+I (Win) or SHIFT+CMD+I (mac)